How does a Neural Net handle an unseen class for a Categorical Feature?
Let's say I train a Neural Net, and I have a Categorical Feature X.
During training, there are only 3 classes seen in feature X; A, B, C.
Now, let's say I want to make predictions from this trained model - but there is now a fourth class, D, that appears in feature X.
How does the Neural Net handle this? It hasn't been trained on any examples belonging to class D?

"Open set" is the keyword you want. Google "open set learning/recognition/classification".

There is no "the Neural Net". You can choose among many many different architectures.

Typically feature X would be presented to the NN via
one hot
encoding.
So we have three (boolean) indicator variables, denoting
the presence of A, B, or C.
If the problem domain admits of D or E values
there is simply no way to represent them,
without redoing the whole representation.
At which point we would likely retrain.
If we anticipate that novel classes could arise in future,
we might choose to model a "miscellaneous" class from the outset.
Then D and E could be assigned the misc. label
when we eventually encounter them.

Here is a separate difficulty.
Imagine that X is our most informative feature.
And we never observe an instance of class B in the training data.
Then at inference time the model is unlikely to have good
predictive power when it encounters out-of-sample instances
which do contain B.
